# lua project on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, lua

I try in stall luaEclipse on Eclipse follow the instruciton

http://luaeclipse.luaforge.net/manual.html#installation

but I try to add new lua file to a lua project, it reported:

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Lua Project Builder' on project 'testLua'.
Could not initialize class org.keplerproject.luajava.LuaState
```

Welcome any comment

Comment: I managed to run it _once_, by using 3.4 (if I remember correctly) version of Eclipse. The problem is finding out which LuaEclipse version goes with which Eclipse version. If you really need IDE for Lua I would suggest using IDEA instead - works out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use Eclipse, I'd advise using [Koneki Lua Development Tools](http://www.eclipse.org/koneki/ldt/) instead, it's more up to date and, last time I checked, works just fine with the latest Eclipse 3.7.

Answer (score 0):

Go to
Help>Eclipse Marketplace
and in search bar search "lua"

You will get "Lua Development Tools" install it restart your Eclipse

Enjoy